# Rust TcpStream write/write_all confusing behavior

Tags: rust, network-programming

## Purpose

Testing a webserver implementation on `The Rust Programming Language`

## Problem encountered:

TcpStream.write_all(some_large_file) wouldn't work, details below:

```
let contents = &fs::read(filename).unwrap()[..];
let response_headers = format!(
    "{}\r\nContent-Length: {}\r\n{}\r\n\r\n",
    status_line,
    contents.len(),
    content_type(filename)
);

stream.write_all(response_headers.as_bytes()).unwrap();

if let Err(e) = stream.write_all(contents) {
    println!("Error: {:?}", e)
}
stream.flush().unwrap();
```

Simple html file can be served without any issue, but a mkv file of 2GB would incur the error: `Error: Os { code: 22, kind: InvalidInput, message: "Invalid argument" }`

so it didn't write a single byte to the client: `2021-06-27 16:41:57 (0,00 B/s) - Connection closed at byte 0. Retrying.`

The `InvalidInput` kind of confuses me, as far as I can see, the contents is `&[u8]` for sure, what could be possible for this?

But I think this error for write(2) system call is that:

```
EINVAL  fd is attached to an object which is unsuitable for 
        writing; or the file was opened with the O_DIRECT flag, and
        either  the  address  specified  in  buf,  the value 
        specified in count, or thefile offset is not suitably 
        aligned.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See linux `write(2)` man page https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html

> On Linux, write() (and similar system calls) will transfer at
> most 0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of
> bytes actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and
> 64-bit systems.)